# Sorting a JSON array and echoing out with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

So currently I have a JSON array that looks like this

```
"series": [{
        "book": 1,
        "chapter": 1,
        "title": "Title of this chapter",
    },
    {
        "book": 1,
        "chapter": 2,
        "title": "Title of this chapter",
    },
    {
        "book": 1,
        "chapter": 3,
        "title": "Title of this chapter",
    },
    {
        "book": 2,
        "chapter": 1,
        "title": "Title of this chapter",
    },
    {
        "book": 2,
        "chapter": 2,
        "title": "Title of this chapter",
    }]
```

I need to echo it out with jQuery so I can do $.each for each book and within that do an $.each for each chapter.

Currently I have done $.each and then appended the results to the page and then tried to sort it with an external jQuery plugin, but to no avail.

Comment: Is requirement to sort objects within array by "chapter" ?, ascending ? What is expected result ? Can include `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly: You don't need a jQuery plugin to sort the rendered DOM. Just sort the array before rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that JSON, you'll need to create an intermediate array of books to group together all the chapters of a given book. Then, on that intermediary structure (which is now an array of `book` objects) you can loop over them and spit out the chapters.

```
var json = //your JSON object
var books = {};
$.each(json.series,function(i,book) {
   if(!books.hasOwnProperty(book.book)) {
      books[book.book] = [];
   }
      books[book.book].push(book);
});

//now that you have each book in it's own array
$.each(books,function(i,book) {
   $.each(book,function(i,chapter) {
       console.log('Book ' + chapter.book + ', Chapter ' + chapter.chapter + ':' + chapter.title);
   });
});
```

If it's at all possible that your books/chapters are not in order, then you'll need to sort them first. Starting with your original JSON object:

```
json.series.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.book-b.book || a.chapter-b.chapter;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    var json = '{"series":[{"book":"1","chapter":"1","title": "Title of this chapter"},{"book":"2","chapter":"2","title": "Title of this chapter"}]}';

    var serieslist = $.parseJSON(json);
    var series_books = {};
    $.each(serieslist.series, function(index,book){
       series_books.push(book);
    });

   $.each(series_books,function(i,book) {
      $.each(book,function(i,chapter) {
        //do what you need to here ...
      });
   })
```

Hopefully this helps, use $.parseJSON to parse out the JSON string into usable objects, then manipulate them as you please.